# Changing a 3D world camera's "up direction"

Tags: math, opengl

I am having issues following a tutorial on creating a "camera class" for a 3d world.

EDIT: More tutorial links

Tutorial text: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera

Camera code: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/7.3.camera_mouse_zoom/camera_mouse_zoom.cpp

Complete example code: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/7.3.camera_mouse_zoom/camera_mouse_zoom.cpp

I had a lot of initial success, however, I need to change the camera's view of what "up" in the world is as my level and 3d assets are rotated so that -Z is up instead of Y. But when I tried changing the "World_Up" to be xyz(0, 0, -1) I am seeing very strange disorienting behavior that is difficult to describe where moving the mouse up and down has no effect on pitch etc.

I need to determine how to make my camera's behavior to be correct when "World_Up" is changed - right now it only works with the standard xyz(0, 1, 0) orientation.

```
   Y                    -Z                

   |                     |          
   |                     |          
   /-------- Z     To    /-------- Y
  /                     /             
 /                     /         

X                     X
```

My code sample is below - my apologies that its in an unusual language, but it should be understandable. *EDIT: The tutorial link (in C++) above has almost the exact same calculations so if you want to ignore my example and discuss the tutorial thatd be fine.*

The meat of the calculations are within **Move**, **Update**, and **View**

```
  ------------
  -- Camera --
  ------------

  CAMERA_ZOOM        : constant Real := 45.0;
  CAMERA_YAW         : constant Real := 0.0;---90.0;
  CAMERA_PITCH       : constant Real :=  0.0;
  CAMERA_SPEED       : constant Real :=  2.5;
  CAMERA_SENSITIVITY : constant Real :=  0.01;
  CAMERA_FOV : constant Real := 45.0;

  type Direction_Kind is (Forward_Direction, Backward_Direction, Left_Direction, Right_Direction);

  class type Camera_State is 
      function View return Matrix_4D;
      procedure Update;
      ...
      procedure Move (Dir : Direction_Kind; Start_Time : Time);
      procedure Look (X_Offset, Y_Offset : Int; Clamp : Bool := True);
  private
      Sensitivity  : Real      := CAMERA_SENSITIVITY;
      Zoom         : Real      := CAMERA_ZOOM;
      Move_Speed   : Real      := CAMERA_SPEED;
      Yaw          : Real      := CAMERA_YAW;
      Pitch        : Real      := CAMERA_PITCH;
      Right        : Vector_3D := ZERO_VECTOR_3D;
      Up           : Vector_3D := ZERO_VECTOR_3D;
      Position     : Vector_3D := ZERO_VECTOR_3D;
      Direction    : Vector_3D := ZERO_VECTOR_3D;

      -- !!! This works but (0.0, 0.0, -1.0) does not !!!
      World_Up     : Vector_3D := (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  end Camera;

  World_Camera : Camera_State;

  class body Camera_State is
    ...
    function View return Matrix_4D is
      (Look_At (Position, Position + Direction, Up));

    procedure Move (Dir : Direction_Kind; Start_Time : Time) is
      begin
        case Dir is
          when Backward_Direction => Position := Position + (Direction * Real_32 (Clock - Start_Time)  * Move_Speed);
          when Forward_Direction  => Position := Position - (Direction * Real_32 (Clock - Start_Time)  * Move_Speed);
          when Right_Direction    => Position := Position - (Normal (Cross (Direction, Up)) * Real_32 (Clock - Start_Time) * Move_Speed);
          when Left_Direction     => Position := Position + (Normal (Cross (Direction, Up)) * Real_32 (Clock - Start_Time) * Move_Speed);
        end case;
      end;

    procedure Look (X_Offset, Y_Offset : Int; Clamp : Bool := True) is
      begin
        Yaw   := Yaw   + Sensitivity * (Real_32 (X_Offset) * (100.0 / Real_32 (Window_Width.Get))) ;
        Pitch := Pitch - Sensitivity * (Real_32 (Y_Offset) * (100.0 / Real_32 (Window_Height.Get))) ;
        if Clamp then
          if Pitch > (PI / 2.0) - 0.01 then
            Pitch := (PI / 2.0) - 0.01;
          end if;
          if Pitch < -(PI / 2.0) + 0.01 then
            Pitch := -(PI / 2.0) + 0.01;
          end if;
        end if;
        Update;
      end;

    procedure Update is
      begin
        Line ("Yaw: "   & Yaw'Wide_Image);
        Line ("Pitch: " & Pitch'Wide_Image);
        Direction := Normal (Vector_3D'(X => Cos (Yaw) * Cos (Pitch),
                                        Y => Sin (Pitch),
                                        Z => Sin (Yaw) * Cos (Pitch)));
        Right := Cross (Direction, World_Up);
        Up    := Normal (Cross (Right, Direction));
      end;

  end Camera;
```

World with Y being up:

[image]

Comment: You might want to add a language tag.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant for this question - consider it pseudo code

Comment: If you want to see the original C++ version I provided a link at the top with almost exactly the same calculations. If someone wanted to use that to explain a solution (in C++) that would be perfectly fine @BDL

Comment: Is it just me or are both of your axis-systems incorrect? I.e. neither is right-handed. Usually if you rotate a system so that the X-axis replaces the Y-axis, then a "normal screw" along the Z axis should move in positive z-direction. That does not apply to the two shown systems, both would see a z-screw moving towards negative.

Comment: "Difficult to describe" is maybe not descriptive enough.  Especially if you aren't showing the mouse code.  You said that moving the mouse causes no change in pitch.  I assume, if working correctly, the change in pitch would come from calling `look` with a non-zero `Y_Offset`.  Can you verify that's happening?

Comment: I am showing the mouse code its "Look" which getts called by a "callback" function which in turn gets triggered in a separate input thread. If you want to see more about how it works check out the below:

https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera
https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/7.3.camera_mouse_zoom/camera_mouse_zoom.cpp

Comment: @Wyck there are changes in pitch but it is small and it seems restricted. When I change world_up to be -z its almost as if my feet and head and left and right instead of up and down even though the camera displays the correct orientation.

Comment: Fix your models before they're used in your program.

Comment: @3Dave well a Doom 3 level is encoded in a special format which is a pain to work with and compile (theres some 100s of models and 10s of levels all with negative Z begin up which would have to be batch converted and exported from Blender/Radiant) and anyways... I would like my code to handle rotating the camera if I choose to, but thanks for the derogatory response

Comment: @RWilco8 It's not a derogatory response. It's the correct solution. No matter the source and complexity of your model, *eventually* you wind up with vertex lists. Transfoming them before entering your update/render loop is trivial. Transfoming or otherwise "fixing" model data at load time, or in a preprocessing bake step, is a common requirement. I apologize if my comment came across as trite - that wasn't my intent.

Comment: @3Dave perhaps i was being sensitive. I have been working on converting them for a while which has been demoralizing - maybe I was taking some frustration out on you. Sorry <3

Comment: @RWilco8 No worries! I've been there more times than I care to remember. My thought was that transforming the models up front would save you a lot of trouble later on, having to adapt camera controls, matrix composition, and anything else that assumes "Z forward, Y up".

Comment: There is a direct Ada parser for Doom 3 levels here: https://globe3d.sourceforge.io/ - just in case...

Comment: Yep thanks @zerte , that used a parser generator (unreadable code) and does not handle the multiple files a level consists of (cm, proc, aas, map) - I have had contact with the author - nice guy : ). If you are curious I am using all of my own stuff though - custom system layer (no SDL), OpenGEX parsers (which are multithreaded) and scripts to convert doom 3 assets to OpenGEX/OpenDDL, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background

By defining a global sense of *up* you're introducing a convention that allows you to determine ***roll*** of the camera given only its ***forward*** direction.  This convention works as long as you're not looking directly up or directly down.  We as humans like this because our eyes are beside each other and we have to deal with weird feelings in our vestibular system when our heads are tipped to the side.  Keep both ears level at the same altitude and you're good. :)

### Here's how it works

The tutorial has the following definition of a forward vector from yaw and pitch

```
if (pitch > 89.0f)
    pitch = 89.0f;
if (pitch < -89.0f)
    pitch = -89.0f;

glm::vec3 front;
front.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
front.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
front.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
cameraFront = glm::normalize(front);
```

This vector points somewhere in the xz plane when pitch is zero and when pitch is high (up to a max of 89°) it approaches the vector (0,1,0) and when pitch is low (up to a min of -89°) it approaches the vector (0,-1,0).

The camera matrix calculation performs a traditional ***look-at*** operation [explained here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera), which begins with this `cameraFront` vector being a *forward* vector and attempts to figure out an orthogonal *right* vector by taking the cross product of `cameraFront` and the `cameraUp` vector.  The range limiting of pitch ensures that *front* and `cameraUp` will never be colinear, and so it is always possible to determine which way is *right* relative to *up*.  The only time that *right* doesn't make sense is if you are looking straight up or straight down -- in those cases, any direction could be right (by rolling the camera along its principal axis) and it would be ambiguous to try to derive *right* from *forward* alone..

### Here's what you did wrong

Now if all you did was change the `cameraUp` vector to (0,0,1), without changing the way that pitch and yaw are defined, then you now introduce a problem that you can easily get a `cameraFront` vector that is colinear with (0,0,1).  If the pitch is zero, then yaw=90° yields `cameraFront`=(0,0,1) and yaw=-90° yields `cameraFront`=(0,0,-1).  Both of these cases will yield a singular matrix (no solution) for the camera matrix because the cross product with `cameraFront` and `cameraUp` is zero, meaning `cameraRight` is zero, and the whole thing falls apart.

In actual practice the vector won't be exactly zero because of the nature of floating point, but it won't give a good stable calculation of an orthogonal camera matrix due to the cross product being zero (or infinitesimally close to zero).

### Here's how you can fix it

So if you want to change `cameraUp` to be (0,0,1), then it makes sense that you should probably rework the definition of pitch and yaw as well.  You would keep the limit that pitch ranges from -89 to +89 but make it so that pitch=0 yields vectors in the xy plane instead of the xz plane.  Essentially, pick a new vector for yaw=0, pitch=0 and make sure it's a vector in the xy plane.  (If I may boldly make an assumption:  +x is probably still naturally *right*.  So yaw=0 probably points down the y axis?  Just my own assumption.)

But it's the code that I excerpted (that computes a front vector from yaw and pitch) that needs to be reswizzled to play nicely with your definition of *up* being (0,0,1).

At the end of the day, just a relabelling of the axes is all you need.  Here's one way to do it:

```
front.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
front.y = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
front.z = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
```